# C# Handling Nested JSON

Tags: c#, json

Need some help in handling nested JSON.

I'm sure of the structure for Property1. For Property2 I'm unsure of the structure. So I need to make Property2 to accept a generic JSON.

```
   public class Property1
    {
        public string property1Name { get; set; }
        public string property1Description { get; set; }
        public Property2 prop2Data { get; set; }
    }
       public class Property2
    {
        public string genericJSON {get; set; }
    }

.
.
.   
        string json = @"{
        'property1Name': 'Name1',
        'property1Description': 'Prop1 Description',
        'prop2Data': { 'genericKey1':100,'genericKey2':"something", 'newKey':"something else" }
    }";
    
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Property1>(json);
```

I'm unsure how to deserialize Property2 and read the values from it.
Any guidance for handling this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try deserializing to Dictionary<string, string> or possibly Dictionary<string, object>

Comment: The answer really depends upon what prop2Data can be. For sure it is NOT a string. It could be a class with 3 properties (genericKey1, genericKey2 and newKey) or something entirely different. What does `prop2Data` can contain?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Newtonsoft.Json you can then use

`JObject prop2data = JObject.Parse(yourJson);`

then you can work with its properties.